# JavaScript Max Information Density

Tags: javascript, tostring, sha256, information-theory

#### Simple question:

I need to store a signed 32-bit integer as a string and convert it back later, the more information density / shorter the string the better. The code that I'm already using is

```
var num;
var str = num.toString(36);
var num2 = parseInt(str, 36);
```

The default radix used in toString is 10 and the max radix is 36. Is there a way to use a greater radix, hopefully even 128 or 256?

#### Less simple question:

I'm using this to store a SHA-256 hash, which is an array of length 8 with 32-bit elements. Is there a more efficient storage method for this over a comma-delimited list of the above strings?

Comment: Your "short" question is larger than the long one :-)

Comment: I noticed that when I posted it. I changed the headings to better reflect the content of the questions

Comment: Take a look at Javascript's [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)

Comment: What is your definition of "string"? (If it's "sequence of bytes", then anything goes).

Comment: Where and how are you going to store the hash?

Comment: @Barmar that was good information, but not for this

Comment: @Bergi the type checker says "must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object". so yes, anything goes really, but I think the limitation here is the sequence of bytes must have all bytes human-readable and not some special formatting character. radix 36 would work (0-9, a-z), but I could also include other characters(!@#$%^&*()-_=+ etc) if need be. As far as how I'm going to store the hash, I'm going to encrypt it with pgp and decrypt it later. The method accepts all arrays, but the hash array contains values outside 0-255 and pgp decrypt spits out garbage

Comment: @AndrewLeonard [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) it is then. You still haven't said what API you are using, but if it takes an `ArrayBuffer` you should definitely go with that (or an `Uint8Array` on it), and ignore the limitation of human-readability.

Comment: @Bergi I guess so